# Touch locations UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to resize an image using the `UIPinchGesture` recognizer and in order to carry that out I need to find the location of the center point upon which the pinching is focused on.

Originally I thought about creating a midpoint calculation for the center point based on the two touched points. The problem is that for some reason the returned points using the touch indexes are not the touch locations that are applied on screen.

For example, when I tried zooming using a touch that was approximately at (333, 187) and another at (1000, 563) the returned locations of the touches were (496, 279) and (170, 95).
What exactly are `UITouch 1` and `UITouch 2` the indexes of? How can I find the center-point value?

```
func handlePinchGesture(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){

    // Finds the midpoint location of the pinch gesture
    var touch1 = gesture.locationOfTouch(0, inView: self.view)
    var touch2 = gesture.locationOfTouch(1, inView: self.view)
    var midPointX = (touch1.x + touch2.x)/2
    var midPointY = (touch1.y + touch2.y)/2
    var touchedPoint = CGPointMake(midPointX, midPointY)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the center-point value

You don't have to find it. The gesture recognizer gives it to you. It is the gesture recognizer's `locationInView:`.

Comment: Also it seems a little odd for you to be manually resizing an image in response to a pinch gesture when that behavior is built right into a UIScrollView for you already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the touch location:

```
@objc func onGesture(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
     print("Location", gesture.location(ofTouch: 0, in: nil))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint centerPoint = [recognizer locationInView: self.view];
```

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/locationInView:):

> The returned value is a generic single-point location for the gesture computed by the UIKit framework. It is usually the **centroid** of the touches involved in the gesture.

This will give you the center. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I tried using the locationInView, however it still returns a point that is not in the center of the view, even though my gesture is centered in the view. To be more specific, the returned point was 333, 187 which is quite oddly a quarter of the the scene width and length, but not half.